# EMC-BCI. Coil injection and probe were calibrated at 100 ohm

Tags: emc, coil, probe, calibration

As the title says my coil injection and coil probe were calibrated into 100 ohm loop line Impedance and it resulted an insertion loss (dB) for the coil injection.

[image]

and transfer impedance (dBΩ) coil probe.

[image]

To be able to use them in my system I need the insertion loss (dB) and transfer impedance (dBΩ) to be calibrated at 50 ohms and my question is:

**Is there a way to calculate and to find out the insertion loss (dB) and transfer impedance (dBΩ) for the 50 ohm line based on the files/graphs that I have?**

I am trying to find a way to use the following formulas but I don't have the complete information (always missing a variable).

[image]

All would be easy if I new what power (W) they used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make a simple answer for my question:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]